# Killing Child Process if no response

Tags: linux

Environment: Linux / Scripting: Bash

I am querying around 100 records from database and for each record I am executing SFTP test/check in background using performTestWrapper.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is at the end of one minute, go through pending process which have not completed:

- Issue a Kill Signal on Child
- Child will trap this kill signal and do post processing like cleaning up its file.

Aim is to perform SFTP check across 100 server and fail if no response or stuck session for over 1 minute.

Problem I am facing:

1. I am unable to pull in CHILD PID outside of while loop. The scope of variable ends in while loop itself.
2. How can I send a signal to function call that is executed in background to terminate and do a post processing.

.

```
isql -S$APPQUERY -U$APPUSER -P$APPPWD -s"|" -w8192 <<EO_ISQL  | tail -n +3  |
set nocount on
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from TableName
go
EO_ISQL
while IFS="|" read dummy Id Col1 Col2 Col3
do
   performTestWrapper &
   export CHILDPID="$CHILDPID $!"
done
sleep 60
echo $CHILDPID # This is Blank
```

Comment: what's wrong with something like `timeout 60 yourjobhere` ?

Comment: Yeah, if you update your `performTestWrapper` to handle a particular signal (pick one that works for you, or use the default `SIGTERM` of timeout) and then run whatever postprocessing you want to do when it receives it, should also solve your second problem

Comment: Thank you, let me check to see if timeout works on function call.  Also, will try SIGTERM workaround. I will post an update.